# Serialize CSV files for ajax request in ASP app

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, forms, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've a form composed by a Kendo combobox and a Kendo file upload:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Methode", "controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p> Select country </p>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("country")
        .DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value")
        .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => {
            read.Action("GetMonth", "BudgetStage");
        });
    }))
    <p> Select a .CSV file: </p>
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { accept = ".csv" })
    )
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button k-primary" />
    <input type="button" value="Ajax" class="k-button k-primary" onclick="postData(this) 
}
```

Here is my C# controller code:

```
public JsonResult methode(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, string country)
{
    return Json("It's OK !", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This works when I click on the submit button, the controller receives files and string values but I need to display the Json returned value from my page.

To do that, I use this ajax function:

```
function postData(button) {
    var form = $(button).parents('form');
    if (form.kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I click on the Ajax button, the backend method is call, return the Json value and my JS code display it. 
The problem is I receive the string value but not the selected CSV file (null).

How can I send the file and the string and display the returned Json value ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `form.serialize()` doesn't really work in this scenario. With kendo it shouldn't be different to ASP.NET MVC + JavaScript, so basically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) should help you.